# State in React for no reason undefined?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-state

I am trying to access and change my state under React Component with setState. Somehow i get error `'iscreateor' is not defined` but i have defined it in my state. What could be error here? Thanks in advance!

My class component where i have state:

```
state = {
        training: {},
        iscreator: false
    }

componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.token == this.state.training.coach) {
                this.setState({
                    iscreator: true
                });
                console.log(iscreator)
            }else{}
    }
```

Comment: It’s in your state—it’s a property of an object, not a reference of its own.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference `console.log(this.state.iscreator)`

Comment: Why could it be that when my state token is equal to training.coach value 'iscreator' value doesn't still change to true? Would i want to use something else than componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

Write `console.log(this.state.iscreator)` instead of `console.log(iscreator)`.

OR

Declare a constant referencing `iscreator` in the state, like:

`const {iscreator} = this.state;`

Then you can write `console.log(iscreator)` and it'll work.